# manipulating input value and content inside paragraph

Tags: html, css

I was trying to manipulate the content inside the **`<p>`tag**. I want to target each element inside the paragraph. I have the following:

```
   <p class="num">123456789</p>
```

This is number is generated through a form and I wanted to add padding to each number through css so, is it possible? I tried a few things myself but it did not help.

my CSS:

```
   *p.num {padding-right:5px;}
   p.num * {padding-right:5px;}
```

Another thing is I was also trying to manipulate the value of input my code is:

```
   <input type="text" value="Name" placeholder="Name" />
```

I have used both value and placeholder because older IE does not support placeholder and that is why I wanted to target value so that I can disable it in new browsers. I have tried a few things on this one:

```
   input[value="Name"] {font-size:0;}
   input[value="Name"] {display:none;}
```

The first one zeroes out the placeholder as well and the second one hides the the input completely. So, I want to know if is there any possible CSS by which I can achieve this?

Comment: On the first part of the question, do you want some space between the numbers? You could use `letter-spacing: 5px` for that. On the second part, what is the desired result?

Comment: So what you want to do is to display **placeholder** in new browsers and **value** in the old ones??

Comment: @LinkinTED the desired result is both being displayed on modern browsers and that I don't want.

Comment: @Nivedita yes I would like it that way

Comment: Upto which version of IE you don't want to show placeholder?

Comment: I have posted an answer. That should help you.

Answer (score 3):

For first question, the solution is pretty simple:

use this CSS rule,

```
p.num {
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the letter spacing property?
You would need to create an ID or class for the input box like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="Name" placeholder="Name" />
```

and it's css would be something like this:

```
#name{ letter-spacing: 3px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your label says MANIPULATING INPUT AND PARA . SO i give you an example how to manipulate it.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/8ey8a/)

**Explanation**

```
  <form class="formclass">
    <p class="num">213213</p>
    <p class="num">213</p>
    <p class="notNum">sadas</p>

    <input type="text" value="vals"></input>
 </form>
```

**CSS**

```
.formclass p.num 
 {
   color: red;
 }

.formclass input[value="vals"]
{
   color: brown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your first question you can try jquery

```
$('.num').css('padding-right','5px');
```

or basic more than jquery you can write pure css

```
.num{ padding-right:5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For spacing between letters, use:

```
p.num{letter-spacing:2px;}
```

For displaying content according to browser type, you will have to use **conditional comments**:

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place content here to target all Internet Explorer users.
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
Place content here to target all users not using Internet Explorer.
<![endif]>

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
Place content here to target users of Internet Explorer 8 or higher.
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
Place content here to target users of Internet Explorer 6 or lower (less than 7).
<![endif]-->
```

This should help you.[Read more](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/detect/detect-ie.html)

You may also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263891/simple-way-to-check-if-placeholder-is-supported) on Stackoverflow itself.

Comment: I am already using less than IE 9 conditional comment and a different CSS file for those browsers but need a CSS solution.

Comment: I don't think its possible through pure CSS as per my knowledge, you may either use HTML or jacascript, or wait for other answers.